# Unable to connect with arcgis server while recording using jmeter proxy setting with iPAD

Tags: jmeter, arcgis-server

We have iPAD and Jmeter 3.0 version for recording mobile performance script. We have setup iPad and Jmeter proxy setting as mentioned on many sites. Our application is native mobile application.

When we try record after setting proxy able to record login and some of requests but when we try to do synchronization activity then request goes to “arcGIS server” and it says "`Unable to sync with arcgis server`" message. Later on it does not record any request in jmeter.

**# In Jmeter logs:**

```
2016/07/14 20:00:37 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: [53176] Problem with SSL certificate for 'www.arcgis.com'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake 

2016/07/14 20:00:37 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: [53175] Problem with SSL certificate for 'securearcgis.datadoors.net'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Remote host closed connection during handshake 

2016/07/14 20:00:57 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored: ib40f47e4-8a50-4ed1-b778-9c66b2e072fc_0.geodatabase
```

**Has anybody encountered an issue while recording arcgis server requests using Jmeter?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate onto the iPAD device. In case of SSL recording JMeter acts as [MITM proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) and dummy certificate is required to decrypt data and be able to record the traffic.

The easiest way of installing the certificate is sending `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file (it's being generated in JMeter's "bin" folder when you launch [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)) somewhere by email and open that email attachment on the iPAD.

Another solution is using [Mobile Recorder service](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Recorder-Mobile-Recorder-), in that case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates, moreover Mobile Recorder can export JMeter tests in so-called "SmartJMX" mode with automated correlation of dynamic parameters so you won't have to detect them, develop regular expressions, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. I have installed "ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt" due to which one of downloading map scenario worked well from arcGIS and able to see http requests. Howevere where i sync date to arcGIS server its just show task started but quickly gives "Unable to connect with arcgis server"